Update query on HIVE based on a regex
I have the following scenario:
There is a hive table with columns as shown



_id
cdn_url




abc123
https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net/images/img1.png


xyz234
https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net/images/img2.png


pqr345
https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net/images/img3.png



I want to update the cdn_url for records which have some cdn_url associated with them. There are some blank ('') or NULL entries as well.
Updation should "replace" the CDN domain from  https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net to the new one, say: https://newcdnpattern.cloudfront.net. The path following the CDN domain remains same for all concerned entries.
Is there any substring or regex based updation query I could run here?
Thanks in advance.

Given that the URL prefix you are targeting would likely only ever occur at the start of the CDN URL, a basic replacement should work:
UPDATE yourTable
SET cdn_url = REPLACE(cdn_url,
                      'https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net',
                      'https://newcdnpattern.cloudfront.net)
WHERE cdn_url LIKE 'https://jjffkk.cloudfront.net%';


Ok, thanks. I'm new to hive so didn't know this kind of functionality support is there directly. I'll try this and by the looks of it, should work fine.

However, will this affect NULL or empty fields, causing some error/exception? @Tim Biegeleisen

@vish4071 You are right Vishnu, there should also be a WHERE clause.
